# Change language based on location/browser language settings in react with i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I need to change the language of my app based on the user location and/or browser language settings. 
How would I do that in i18next?
It has to be i18Next, because the project is already setup to work with it and using another library would take me ages to refactor to work properly.

This is my code so far. I understand I need to do something in the backend part, just don't know what.

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-xhr-backend";

i18n
  .init({
    backend: {

      loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json"
    },
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: false,
    keySeparator: false,
  });

export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used i18next-browser-languagedetector. Docs and examples are here https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector. The strings 

`const options = {
  order: ['querystring', 'navigator'],
  lookupQuerystring: 'lng'
}`
and in init 
`.use(LanguageDetector)
.use(initReactI18next)`

will be add in your i18n.js file.